# React-Native modals without backdrop and with click through

Tags: react-native

How can I create a UI that keeps the header of the last page visible and pressable?

Views are supposed to slide up and stop below the parent's header(like a deck of cards). Clicking on the parent header closes the child views.

View 1

```
---------------------------
Stack Navigator - Header
Screen 1 Header
Screen 1 Content
..
..
..
..
Screen 1 Content

---------------------------
```

View 2

```
---------------------------
Stack Navigator - Header
Screen 1 Header
Screen 2 Header
Screen 2 Content
...
...
...
Screen 2 Content

---------------------------
```

View 3

```
---------------------------
Stack Navigator - Header
Screen 1 Header
Screen 2 Header
Screen 3 Header
Screen 3 Content
...
...
Screen 3 Content

---------------------------
```

I tried react-native modal. But it always blocking touches to the view in the background. I think it is because, the backdrop is always there as full screen, even if it is transparent or modal is tiny.

Comment: So, RN Modal is a workaround for your problem? I could post an answer to dismiss the Modal when tapping the background

Comment: Dismissing the modal: we can only dismiss the topmost modal, right? If Pressed on `Screen 1 Header` of `View 3` both modals, Screen2 and Screen3, should be closed for me.